# How to access a specific menu item dropdown with CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using joomla and helix_ultimate theme, and this what helix theme developers provided for accessing every menu item dropdown.

```css
.sp-megamenu-parent .sp-dropdown .sp-dropdown-inner {display:none;}
```

But I need to access only home menu item drop down and hide it. Here is also screenshot of that menu item when I inspect it.

[html of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lbCX.png)

Comment: You'll need to add the HTML of the menu for someone to be able to give a specific answer (can you update your question, please?), but probably you can use `nth-child` or `nth-of-type`.

Comment: you can have this selector in your CSS `a[href="joomla_3.9.15/index"] { ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, .menuhome class to access dropdown with adjacent sibling combinator (+)

```
.menuhome + .sp-dropdown .sp-dropdown-inner {
   display: none;
 }
```

[details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Comment: Welcome. StackOverflow does not like code-only answers (makes it harder for people scanning many answers to figure out what's going on). Please edit your answer and add a line or two of text that explains what your answer is solving.